# admin laravel Notification system

Tags: laravel

Hi guys am working on an back-end system(admin) in laravel. I would like to send notifications realtime to the admin whenever a user makes some changes from thier side. for instance if a user creates a new project, i would like for the admin to be notified when the user submits the project details to the database. Please help me with a model of the same. thanks

Comment: This is very broad, can you clarify what aspect of the problem you are struggling with? Have you tried anything, thought about approaches? Have you looked into what shows up when Googling `laravel admin notification`?

Comment: @Pekka I googled it and found out some technologies like Pusher and the use of laravel events but am little confused about how to go about the whole thing... sorry,still a newbie..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very broad and you don't specify a clear problem. However, for real time notifications I'd suggest you to look at the following libraries: Socket IO, Ratchet and Pusher.

Comment: do i use all of those libraries all the same time for realtime

Comment: No, you only need one of them. Which one you gonna choose depends on your specific needs.

Comment: apparently when you are listening to the port 3000, can you php artisan serve at the same time?